# Create table that lists worksheet visibility

Tags: vba, excel

Following my previous question [Create a table that lists macros in a workbook or worksheet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156255/create-a-table-that-lists-macros-in-a-workbook-or-worksheet) here's my Sub to determine worksheet visibility in a workbook. This arises from updating code that used extremely hard to understand logic and several disparate NamedRanges to subsequently hide/reveal sheets.

- Is there a better/optimal to create a string as opposed to what I use: `join(Array(param1, param2,...,paramN), DELIMIT)`? I only have brief exposure to [StringBuilder Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and would like to know how best to do this.

---

```
Public Sub ListWorksheetVisibilityInActiveWORKBOOK()
Const DELIMIT As String = "|", COLSPAN As Long = 2
Dim HEADER As String
Dim inputCell As Range
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim ASU As Boolean

Dim TableName As String

    HEADER = join(Array("SheetName", "Visibility"), DELIMIT)
On Error Resume Next 'Error handling to allow for cancelation
    Set inputCell = GetInputCell("Select where you want the table to go")
    If inputCell Is Nothing Then GoTo CleanExit
On Error GoTo 0 'Clear error handling

    TableName = Application.InputBox("Table name", Default:="WorksheetVisibility")
    If TableName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Table name not entered. No table has been created."
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If

    'Check to avoid overwriting information below
Dim tblVisibility As Range, rngFormulas As Range, rngConstants As Range
    Set tblVisibility = inputCell.Resize(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count + 1, COLSPAN)
On Error Resume Next 'If no cells are found error wont cause issue
    Set rngConstants = tblVisibility.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rngFormulas = tblVisibility.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
On Error GoTo 0 'Clears error handling
    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Or Not rngFormulas Is Nothing Then
Dim Msg As String
        Msg = "Some cells below will be overwritten. Overwrites cannot be undone..." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you wish to proceed?"
        If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Your attention please!") = vbNo Then End
    End If

ASU = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    inputCell.Value2 = HEADER

    Rw = inputCell.row + 1
    Col = inputCell.Column
Dim Value As String
    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Value = join(Array(Ws.Name, Ws.Visible), DELIMIT)
        Cells(Rw, Col).Value2 = Value
        Rw = Rw + 1
    Next

    tblVisibility.Columns(1).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:=DELIMIT

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tblVisibility, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Destination:=inputCell).Name = TableName

CleanExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = ASU
End Sub

Private Function GetInputCell(ByVal Prompt As String) As Range
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set GetInputCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt, Type:=8)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "User Cancelled"
    Set GetInputCell = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't *think* there is a StringBuilder() class in VBA, only some tricks using `Mid`.

> ```
> Const DELIMIT As String = "|", COLSPAN As Long = 2
> Dim HEADER As String
> ```

This is a little confusing, UPPERCASE should indicate a constant, which is does with `DELIMIT` - but `Header` is not (cannot) be a constant. And that leaves me without a `Dim` or a `Const` for `COLSPAN`. Try to be a little more consistent with that - it will be much easier to tell what variables are what.

> ```
> Dim ASU as Boolean
> ASU = Application.ScreenUpdating
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> Application.ScreenUpdating = ASU
> ```

Now, I *know* `ASU` can't be a constant. Maybe `screenIsUpdating`? But then again, I think using a variable to store this is overkill unless you are trying to save the settings of the user - which you aren't

```
Dim screenIsUpdating as Boolean
screenIsUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenIsUpdating
```

This way you store the user's settings, but still turn it off for your procedure.

These variables could use better names, even if `i` and `j` -

> ```
> Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long
> Dim Ws As Worksheet
> ```

`Ws` works, but I don't recommend it, it will start to look pretty messy once you have a lot going on. Also, local variables should start with a lowercase letter [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx).

> ```
> Dim tblVisibility As Range, rngFormulas As Range, rngConstants As Range
> ```

I see `tblVisibility` and think "oh, must be a boolean" - but it's a range. And `rngFormulas` and `rngConstants` seem to have the same issue, which is why they are prefixed with `rng` - yeah?

```
tableRange
formulaRange
constantRange
```

But, what is `constantRange`? If it's constant, it doesn't need a range.

> ```
> Cells(Rw, Col).Value2 = Value
> ```

You did a good job qualifying most things, but this `Cells` isn't qualified - it should be `inputCell.Parent.Cells` - or just give that target sheet a variable.

> ```
> If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Your attention please!") = vbNo Then End
> ```

Here's an `End` again, try to avoid those. Also I think `Msg` (as well as some other fixed strings) could be a `Const`.

> ```
> Rw = inputCell.Row + 1
> Col = inputCell.Column
> Dim Value As String
> For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
>     Value = Join(Array(Ws.Name, Ws.Visible), DELIMIT)
>     Cells(Rw, Col).Value2 = Value
>     Rw = Rw + 1
> Next
> ```

This loop is pretty confusing to me. You are iterating up the rows, but have a loop for the sheets?

```
For index = 1 to Thisworkbook.Worksheets.Count
   targetSheet.Cells(index+1,tableColumn) = Join(Array(Worksheets(index).Name,Worksheets.Visible), DELIMITER)
Next
```

But, for that `Join` string, I would probably do it a different way -

```
Dim index As Long
Dim tableArray() As String
Dim sheetCount As Long
sheetCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
ReDim tableArray(1 To sheetCount, 1 To 2)
For index = LBound(tableArray) To UBound(tableArray)
    tableArray(index, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(index).Name
    tableArray(index, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(index).Visible
Next
```

Arrays are faster and you can just `Transpose` it into your table range. Or *maybe* just [convert the array into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32827905/1161309).

Oh, and your procedure name

> ```
> Public Sub ListWorksheetVisibilityInActiveWORKBOOK()
> ```

Good job on being descriptive, but it's a bit much. `CreateSheetVisibilityTable()` maybe?

Comment: You can *make* a [StringBuilder](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/23788) though :)

Comment: And you can persist Application properties with a [class](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117037/vba-class-to-persist-and-restore-excel-application-properties)

Comment: Working on getting consistent naming.  `ASU` is/was my shorthand for `Application.ScreenUpdating`. It's meant to turn it off for the procedure and turn it back on via the variable since it may have been turned on or off prior and I can't be sure which it will be at run-time. 
rngConstants and rngFormulas are checking for any values that may be overwritten when the table is created.  Good catch on `Cells`.  The loop is for writing the information to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my updated code per @Raystafarian's suggestions. There is no longer any hard `End` and feel like it's in a better spot now.

> Is there a better method of coercing the `-1` results from the visibility field in the table instead of `Copy`/`PasteSpecial`ing onto itself?

```
Public Sub CreateSheetVisibilityTable()
    Dim screenIsUpdating As Boolean
    screenIsUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

    On Error Resume Next                         'Error handling to allow for cancelation
        Dim inputCell As Range
        Set inputCell = GetInputCell("Select where you want the table to go")
        If inputCell Is Nothing Then GoTo CleanExit
    On Error GoTo 0                              'Clear error handling

    Dim tableName As String
    tableName = Application.InputBox("Table name", Default:="WorksheetVisibility")

    If tableName = "False" Then
        MsgBox "Table name not entered. No table has been created."
        GoTo CleanExit
    End If

    Dim theWorkbook As Workbook
    Set theWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook


    Dim sheetCount As Long
    sheetCount = theWorkbook.Worksheets.count

    Dim visibilityTable As Range
    Set visibilityTable = inputCell.Resize(sheetCount + 1, 2)

    'Check to avoid overwriting information below
    On Error Resume Next                         'If no cells are found error wont cause issue
        Dim rangeContainingConstants As Range
        Set rangeContainingConstants = visibilityTable.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        Dim rangeContainingFormulas As Range
        Set rangeContainingFormulas = visibilityTable.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0                              'Clears error handling

    If Not rangeContainingConstants Is Nothing Or Not rangeContainingFormulas Is Nothing Then
        Const Msg As String = "Some cells below will be overwritten. Overwrites cannot be undone..." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you wish to proceed?"
        If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Your attention please!") = vbNo Then GoTo CleanExit
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim tableArray() As String
    ReDim tableArray(0 To sheetCount, 0 To 1)

    tableArray(LBound(tableArray), 0) = "SheetName"
    tableArray(LBound(tableArray), 1) = "Visibility"

    Dim theIndex As Long
    For theIndex = LBound(tableArray) + 1 To UBound(tableArray)
        tableArray(theIndex, 0) = theWorkbook.Worksheets(theIndex).Name
        tableArray(theIndex, 1) = theWorkbook.Worksheets(theIndex).Visible
    Next

    visibilityTable.Value2 = tableArray

    inputCell.Parent.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, visibilityTable, XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes).Name = tableName

    'Coerce to numeric
    With inputCell.Parent.ListObjects.Item(tableName).DataBodyRange.Columns(2)
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = screenIsUpdating
End Sub
```